# Strange behaviour with UITableViewController and UITextFields

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitextfield, uitableview

I'm observing some strange behaviour when working with a `UITableViewController` and `UITextFields` in the cells.

The `UITextFields` delegate is set to the `UITableViewController` and when entering editing mode the tableview scrolls to the relevant cell, and does not obscure the input with the keyboard.

However, when I present another view controller using

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:TRUE  completion:^() {}];
```

And later dismiss it with

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
```

The table stops scrolling and resizing to fit the keyboard.

It does not seem to matter where I call the `presentViewController` method (in the cell, in the headers or in a toolbar)

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1:**

Delegate for my UITextField is set in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` with `cell.textField.delegate = self`

I only override `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated  {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker sendView:@"Some view name"];
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Manually calling

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self viewWillAppear:YES];
}];
```

Fixes it, but i'd still like some input to why this is necessary ?

Comment: Where are you setting the UITextField delegate?

Comment: Can you please post code for viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear and viewWillDisapper/viewDidDisappear ?

Comment: Ok, it looks like `viewWillAppear` does not get called on my `UITableViewController` when i dismiss the `presentedViewController`

If i call `[self viewWillAppear:YES];` in the completion block of `dismissViewControllerAnimated` it seems to work.

Comment: @AkshayShah your request made me check if `viewWillAppear` was called at all when returning from `dismissViewControllerAnimated`, see update 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in the view hierarchy I had missed a call to `[super viewWillAppear:]`.